# Setting a public int to a random number

Tags: java, random, int

I want to make a public int set to a random. But, I have a problem.

```
public static int response = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;

    public static void main(String []args){

        Random rand = new Random();
```

This code doesn't work. I get that since the random is inside of the main method the public int can't retrieve the rand. Is there any way I can have a public int set to a random number?

Comment: Why not just move `response = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;` inside `main` where `rand` is in scope?

Comment: Or add a `private Random rand = new Random();` before the the other...

Comment: So I can use it in a different method.

Comment: @Berin, what "other"?

Comment: @TheChosenSnail, kindly have a look at my simple solution. You can make use of [ThreadLocalRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) class.

Comment: This is one of those times where downvotes confuse me. If this is a duplicate of a popular post (or it has been asked many times before), someone should probably link to it.

Comment: It does have to be static, right? Whether or not it's static is a pretty important part of the question (and will lead to totally different answers). You might want to update the question appropriately.

Comment: I completely agree. Thank you for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ThreadLocalRandom class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html).

`import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;`

```
public static int response = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(6) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [*static initialization block*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), like

```
public static int response;
static {
    Random rand = new Random();
    response = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Field `rand` must be defined in a static context for `response` to reference that field.

Either use this:

```
public static int response = new Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
```

Or simply for a random number can use the static [random()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) method in Math class.

```
public static int response = 1 + (int)(6 * Math.random())
```

If you need to create other random numbers then you can create a private `rand` field.

```
private final static Random rand = new Random();
public static int response = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
```